# Codeigniter form validation set rules to accept numbers and dashes

Tags: codeigniter

I tried setting a rule in codeigniter form validation to accept input such as numbers and dashes. I read the Codeigniter documentation but it doesn't support such thing. Is there any way to write a custom function? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Contact No.', 'numeric');
```

Comment: The [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods) absolutely has the callback validation methods covered.

Answer (score 2):

Within the form validation you can set a custom rule as a callback function (see [this documentation section](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods))

If you set your validation as

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Contact No.', 'callback_my_function');
```

You can set up a function in your controller:

```
function my_function($data)
{
  // your validation code
}
```

The $data parameter is passed through automatically from the field being validated, and you'll need to return true if it validates, or false if it doesn't for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes planned to do that but how can I do it? 
like function contact_num ($str) {
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Now this works for me. Maybe it could help others.

```
// Allow dashes to numbers 
  function numeric_dash ($num) {
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([0-9-\s])+$/D", $num)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: how about adding open and close parenthesis on the regex?